# Chrome select options are blank

Tags: drivers, google-chrome

Sometimes, the options of a select element are blank in Chrome:

[image]

However, it doesn't happen in Firefox or even in Chrome if I move the window to my secondary monitor:

[image]

It appears to be a video driver problem. It is a 5-year old laptop running Linux Mint 17.2, with a Intel Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller.

I've already tried to install Intel video driver (http:// 01.org/linuxgraphics), but as it is developed to work properly in Ubuntu, I followed a tutorial to make it work in Mint but my system crashed and I had to reinstall it from scratch. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

try run chrome with disable gpu acceleration

```
google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu
```

Comment: This does not fix it for me, Elementary 0.4.1 based on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Chrome, please see this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515451). It might help if you star the issue, to indicate that it affects you (and to receive updates when there's activity on it)